# Getting many "disconnected" warning messages on kafka producer but sending messages works correctly

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka

Using aws auth to connect to kafka and getting the following warning every second:

```
10:26:00.055 [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] WARN  o.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - [Producer clientId=producer-1] Bootstrap broker whatever-gravito.kafka.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:9098 (id: -4 rack: null) disconnected
```

This happens with spring boot kafka autoconfiguration:

```
spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers=whatever-gravito.kafka.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:9098
spring.kafka.security.protocol=SASL_SSL
spring.kafka.properties.sasl.mechanism=AWS_MSK_IAM
spring.kafka.properties.sasl.jaas.config=software.amazon.msk.auth.iam.IAMLoginModule required;
spring.kafka.properties.sasl.client.callback.handler.class=software.amazon.msk.auth.iam.IAMClientCallbackHandler
```

There are a few strange things here:

1. **Messages/Events are still sent correctly**.
2. Same server/configuration on my laptop doesn't show this warning and messages are sent correctly.
3. We have a consumer with same configuration that doesn't show this warning and consumes messages correctly.
4. Running with a non-authenticated config (port 9092) doesn't show this warning.

**Any idea what can cause this warning and still have the producer work correctly?**

Config:
spring-kafka:3.0.11 + aws-msk-iam-auth:2.0.3